# Ruby-like C# Zlib string inflate

Tags: c#, zlib, inflate

**End goal:**
I want to read an rxdata file, which is compressed with `Zlib::Deflate.deflate` in Ruby given the state of the program. I'm unable to use `Zlib::Inflate.inflate` in Ruby. Because of that, I looked at C#.

Let's say I have this compressed string in Ruby:

`X\x85\xCBH\xAD\x04\x00\xF0\x15\xD6\x88`

If I were to run `Zlib::Inflate.inflate` on that in Ruby, it'd give me a string which contains `hey`.

Now, if I have this compressed string in C#, is there an easy way to inflate it into a string of `hey`?

I've looked at `Ionic.Zlib` already, but I couldn't get much wiser from it.

---

I don't know much/anything about compression and the like.

Comment: You probably want to use `DeflateStream`. I'd elaborate but I'm on mobile right now

Comment: Would you know which exact methods to use? I've tried a couple things with DeflateStream already but didn't have much luck.
edit: Ah, gotcha.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not an expert in compression myself, there might be different header data or something comparing Ruby's ZLib and C#'s. Note that C# only uses ZLib if you target .NET 4.5 or higher, before it used some other algorithm. Let me try if I can decompress your string.

Comment: Is it possible to get the raw byte values in "normal" hex or decimal numbers? I have no clue how to parse that string you posted and don't know Ruby. I tried compressing "hey" in C# and got something _similar_, yet only consisting of 5 bytes, and don't know how to compare.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that's working in Ruby? I get "Zlib::DataError: incorrect data check" in Ruby for those bytes, which is correct! That zlib stream has an incorrect Adler-32 check value for the data "hey".

Comment: That must be why my output in C# was slightly different! :-)

Comment: It should be. `Zlib::Deflate.deflate('hey')` returns `X\x85\xCBH\xAD\x04\x00\xF0\x15\xD6\x88`.

Comment: `irb(main):004:0> Zlib::Deflate.deflate('hey')
=> "x\x9C\xCBH\xAD\x04\x00\x02~\x01G"`